How to make a column in a table with a float value in SQLite?
I'm making a table in a database, and one of the columns needs to store a float number. However, I keep getting an error under the name of the float value when I ask my SQLiteDatabase to create the table.
I tried declaring the float somewhere that wasn't at the end of my "create table" statement.
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + teams_table_name + " (teamName varchar (50) primary key not null, foreign key (username) references " + users_table_name + " (username), averageBST float(3, 2), foreign key (pkmnOne) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnTwo) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnThree) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnFour) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnFive) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnSix) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName));");
I tried not declaring the number of digits in the float and how many were after the decimal point.
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + teams_table_name + " (teamName varchar (50) primary key not null, foreign key (username) references " + users_table_name + " (username), foreign key (pkmnOne) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnTwo) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnThree) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnFour) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnFive) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnSix) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), averageBST float);");
I tried making "averageBST" all lowercase letters.
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + teams_table_name + " (teamName varchar (50) primary key not null, foreign key (username) references " + users_table_name + " (username), foreign key (pkmnOne) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnTwo) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnThree) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnFour) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnFive) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnSix) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), averagebasestattotal float);");
I tried saying that averageBST cannot be null, although I will never let that happen in the first place.
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + teams_table_name + " (teamName varchar (50) primary key not null, foreign key (username) references " + users_table_name + " (username), foreign key (pkmnOne) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnTwo) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnThree) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnFour) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnFive) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), foreign key (pkmnSix) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), averageBST float not null);");
When I tried these things, I expected the red squiggle underneath "averageBST" to go away. It never did.

If you hover your mouse over the red squiggle, what message pops up? If you change from float to REAL, to better match SQLite's supported types, do you have better results? If you try creating the same table structure outside of Android, such as using SQLite Browser or the command-line client, do you get more useful information about what might be wrong?


How to make a column in a table with a float value?

This is not the issue, rather:-
As per the comment. The syntax error:- is complaining about the word float (not because it is the word float) it is saying that it is not either:-

the closing parenthesis of the list of column names, or
a comma that separates the averageBST column from another column name.


I tried not declaring the number of digits in the float and how many were after the decimal point.

Again, averageBST AvErAgEbSt or whatever, is not the issue, as explained, it is simply close to where the issue is. Case typically only really matters with values.

I tried saying that averageBST cannot be null, although I will never let that happen in the first place.

Again, the NOT NULL constraint is part of the definition of a column and cannot be used when referencing the column in a foreign key constraint.
The fix may well be :-
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + teams_table_name +
            "(" +
            "   teamName varchar (50) primary key not null, " +
            " averageBST REAL ," +
            /* ORIGINAL
            "foreign key (username) references " + users_table_name + " (username, " +
            "averageBST float(3, 2), " +*.
             */
            /*<<<<<<<<<< EXAMPLE OF CORRECT SYNTAX >>>>>>>>>>*/
            "foreign key (username) references " + pkmn_table_name + "(username,averageBST) ," +
            "foreign key (pkmnOne) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), " +
            "foreign key (pkmnTwo) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), " +
            "foreign key (pkmnThree) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), " +
            "foreign key (pkmnFour) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), " +
            "foreign key (pkmnFive) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName), " +
            "foreign key (pkmnSix) references " + pkmn_table_name + " (pkmnName));");

As can be seen the FOREIGN KEY expects the following syntax:-

So you have:-

FOREIGN KEY  which is correct, then
(username, which is correct (syntax wise), and as there is a comma after the column name username, a subsequent column name is required, so
averageBST, BUT

Now the syntax expects wither a ) to denote the end of the list of column names, or a , if another column name is to be provided.
Instead  float( is coded. This being an invalid column name.
Float not an issue  - brief explanation
As for making the column in the referenced table a float. That is dependant upon the data that is stored. In short SQLite is flexible and in many(most) cases any type of data can be stored in any type of column (with some exceptions). See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html
However, FLOAT (REAL) v TEXT can have inherent issues. The following DEMO shows this (see the embedded comments). The following can be run using an SQLite tool and should produce the same results.
/* Just in case not cleaned up */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS f;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t;
/*Create the tables - note the funny!!! column type (will be NUMERIC affinity)*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t (username TEXT PRIMARY KEY, other a_funny_column_type);
/* noting the column level FOREIGN KEY constraint */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS f (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, f_data TEXT, f_username_reference REFERENCES t(username));
/* Add some data noting mathematical and text FP data (BEWARE)*/
INSERT INTO t VALUES
    (10.234,'A'),('10.123','B'),('Fred','C')
;
/* Add some referenced (in theory) data */
/* noting that again mathematical notation and text representation of FP values */
INSERT INTO f(f_data,f_username_reference) VALUES
    ('blah1','Fred')
    ,('blah2',10.234) /* mathematical FP notation*/
    ,('blah2A','10.234') /* text FP notation */
    ,('blah3',10.123)
    ,('blah3A','10.123')
;
/* OUTPUT 1 show the storage type of the username in the t table */
SELECT *, typeof(username) AS stored_type FROM t;
/* OUTPUT 2 show the storage type of the f_username_reference in the f table */
SELECT *, typeof(f_username_reference) AS stored_type FROM f;
/* show the equivalent of  join using a subquery noting that the info_2 column if null would not be joined due to the mismatch between text and real*/
SELECT 
    *,
    /* LIKE effectively casts values to text*/  
    (SELECT f.f_data||': '||f.f_username_reference||' TYPE is stored AS '||typeof(f.f_username_reference) FROM t WHERE t.username LIKE f.f_username_reference) AS info,
    /* if not cast */
    (SELECT f.f_data||': '||f.f_username_reference||' TYPE is stored AS '||typeof(f.f_username_reference) FROM t WHERE t.username = f.f_username_reference) AS info_2,
    (SELECT f.f_username_reference FROM t WHERE CAST(t.username AS FLOAT) = CAST(f.f_username_reference AS REAL)) AS when_cast
    
FROM f;
/* Showing that the type matters (TEXT v REAL) when using a JOIN*/
/* i.e. only 3 rows extracted when  using = BUT 6 rows when CASTing both values to the same*/
SELECT 'P1',* FROM t JOIN f ON t.username = f.f_username_reference
UNION ALL SELECT 'P2',* FROM t JOIN F ON CAST(t.username AS REAL) = CAST(f.f_username_reference AS REAL)
;

/* Cleanup */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS f;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t; 

When run the following outputs are obtained:-
The 1st output is for all rows of the t table:-


As can be seen SQLite considers ALL the values for the username column as being stored as a type of TEXT, even though the first row had a value specified as a mathematical notated FP value.

The 2nd output is for all rows of the f table (that has the FKey constraint):-


Here it can be seen that the values for the f_username_reference column are not of the same storage type.
** this might be a little confusing considering the first result but that is because in the first result the values have to be used for the index.

The 3rd output shows that at times care needs to be taken as, for example, 10.234 and '10.234' are NOT the same value but can either be cast directly or indirectly via LIKE (for example):-

The 4th output is effectively 2 queries concatenated (a UNION) the queries  both use a JOIN but the 2nd CASTS the values. Hence the first (rows with P1) omits the rows where the comparison is not met due to the REAL v TEXT values not being equal, whilst the 2nd set of rows (with P2) overcome the difference:-

